# Installing the latest version of the web3py package under PyPy interpreter (venv)

Tags: web3.py, python

I am trying to install a web3 package under PyPy venv, but unfortunately it does not want to install the latest version (5.3.31).

Instead it installs 4.1.0

OS: Windows 10 (64 bit)

Steps I did:

- Downloaded PyPy binaries from the official website *(PyPy 3.9 and 3.7 tested in the same order)*
- Put binaries on C: disk
- Included PyPy in the `PATH`
- Installed pip with `pypy -m ensurepip` *(pip version 22.0.4 and 22.3 tested)*
- Installed venv with `pypy -m pip install virtualenv`  *(virtualenv-20.16.6)*
- Created venv with `pypy -m virtualenv -p C:\pypy3.7-v7.3.9-win64\pypy3.exe venvname`
- Entered venv where I tried:
- `pip install web3` *gives 4.1.0 version*
- `pypy -mpip install web3` *gives 4.1.0 version*
- `pip install --only-binary :all: web3` *gives 4.1.0 version*
- `pip install -Iv web3==5.31.1`  leads to

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> pywin32>=223; platform_system == "Windows" (from web3) (from versions:
> none)

The problem is probably related to the PyPy interpreter. I haven't noticed such problems with the basic Python 3.10.

Has anyone had success using PyPy along with a web3 module to speed up processing?

Comment: It is unlikely PyPy speeds up any processing, because usually any web3.py speed issues are just because of using low quality node services and not having proper parallerisation. [Here we have some examples how to do high through processing with Web3.py](https://web3-ethereum-defi.readthedocs.io/tutorials/event-reader.html).

Comment: That sounds logical, thank you for that information. However, there are many reports that switching to javascript greatly affects speed. And python, by its nature, is quite slower interpreted by default CPython. I'm also trying to implement and test threading and other asynchronous python features, but I still don't understand how reasonable it is if javascript wins in terms of performance. Maybe it's all just a waste of time, though.

Comment: Those reports are made by people who have no clue what they are doing. Whatever is single thread execution time does not matter in practice as the 99% overhead is IO.